# Is a CDN service worth it for storing images or can I use the MongoDb and my server to serve them?

Tags: image, express, e-commerce, cdn, server-side

I'am building an ecommerce webapplication from scartch and I have to store the images of the products.

Is it worth it to use a service like uploadcare with a dedicated CDN or can I just store them on MongoDb and serve them via an API from my express server?

Currently I made the infrastructure with MongoDb and an API on my server.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question brings answers based on personal opinions, not absolute ones

Comment: @pierpy so it doesnt really mater if I use the server or a CDN?
Would it have an impact on performence or other stuff?